# variadic function to function pointer

Tags: c++, function, variadic-functions

Is There any way to cast a variadic function to a function pointer like this, is it legal? I am asking both for C and for C++, but since this construct exists in both languages, I have put both questions in one.

```
extern int test(int, ...);
auto testptr = (int(*)(int, int, long)) &test;
```

Thanks,
thejack

Comment: C or C++?  They are two different languages.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I corrected it

Comment: Use variadic templates for C++, this will make your function a real `int(int, int, long)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, these types are **not** compatible.

Section 6.2.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Compatible type and composite type" says the following regarding the compatibility of function pointers:

> *3* A composite type can be constructed from two types that are compatible; it is a type that is compatible with both of the two types
>   and satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - If both types are array types, the following rules are applied:
>
>   - If  one  type  is  an  array  of  known  constant  size,  the  composite  type  is  an  array  of that size.
>   - Otherwise,  if  one  type  is  a  variable  length  array  whose  size  is  specified  by  an expression that is not evaluated, the
>       behavior is undefined.
>   - Otherwise,  if  one  type  is  a  variable  length  array  whose  size  is  specified,  the composite type is a variable length array of
>       that size.
>   - Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array of unspecified size, the composite type is a variable length array of unspecified
>       size.
>   - Otherwise,  both  types  are  arrays  of  unknown  size  and  the  composite  type  is  an array of unknown size. The  element  type  of 
>       the  composite  type  is  the  composite  type  of  the  two  element
>       types.
> - **If only  one  type  is  a  function  type  with  a  parameter  type  list  (a  function  prototype), the composite type is a function
>     prototype with the parameter type list.**
> - **If both types are function types with parameter type lists, the type of each parameter in  the  composite  parameter  type  list  is  the 
>     composite  type  of  the  corresponding parameters.**
>
> ...
>
> *5* EXAMPLE     Given the following two file scope declarations:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(), double (*)[3]);
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[]);
> ```
>
> The resulting composite type for the function is:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[3]);
> ```

Section 6.7.6.3p15 states:

> For two  function  types  to  be  compatible,  both  shall  specify 
>   compatible  return  types.  **Moreover,  the  parameter  type 
>   lists,  if  both  are  present,  shall  agree  in  the  number  of
>   parameters  and  in  use  of  the  ellipsis  terminator;** 
>   corresponding  parameters  shall  have compatible types.  If one type
>   has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a
>   function  declarator  that  is  not  part  of  a  function  definition
>   and  that  contains  an  empty identifier list, the parameter list
>   shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter 
>   shall  be  compatible  with  the  type  that  results  from  the 
>   application  of  the default argument promotions.  If one type has a
>   parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function
>   definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both
>   shall agree  in  the  number  of  parameters,  and  the  type  of 
>   each  prototype  parameter  shall  be compatible  with  the  type 
>   that  results  from  the  application  of  the  default  argument
>   promotions  to  the  type  of  the  corresponding  identifier.   (In 
>   the  determination  of  type compatibility  and  of  a  composite 
>   type,  each  parameter  declared  with  function  or  array type is
>   taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with
>   qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.)

In your example:

```
int test(int, ...);
```

This function is compatible with the following:

```
int (*)();            // a function taking an unknown number of parameters and returns an int
int (*)(int, ...);    // a function taking an int and variable parameters after and returns an int
```

But not:

```
int (*)(int, int, long);    // a function taking an int, an int, and a long, and returns an int
```

Because both function type specify a parameter list and because the number of parameters nor does the use of ellipsis agree, the types are not compatible.  Attempting to call a function through an incompatible pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per section 6.3.2.3p8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer.  **If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 4):

C-style variadic functions are their own special beast. Their arguments must be unwrapped with the `va_list` family of functions. There is no compatibility with non-variadic functions, and they are not macros, and no.

Given your use of `auto` I assume that you're asking about C++, despite the double-tagging. [Try to avoid functions like that in C++.](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL50-CPP.+Do+not+define+a+C-style+variadic+function)

Answer (score 2):

You are free to cast a function pointer to a function pointer of a different type, but calling a function through a function pointer of a different type is undefined behaviour. (So the only valid thing you can do with the cast function pointer is to cast it back to rhe correct type.)

Variadic functions are not the same type as functions with a specific number of arguments. So the result of the cast cannot be used to call the function.

If you try it on some compiler, you might find that it does what you expect. But that doesn't make it valid; it may well break on a different platform or compiler version.

(The above is true for both C and C++.)